# Undefined variable despite variable being defined?

Tags: laravel

Users in my app can create their own groups. A Group is displayed on the `groups/show.blade.php` and other users can join said group(s).

I want to show a list of all people who have joined each group.

On the `groups/show.blade.php` page I have the following

```
@if ($joinedUsers)

@foreach($joinedUsers as $joinedUser)

{{$user->name}}

@endforeach

@else
@endif

@endsection
```

The error I get is:

> Undefined variable: group_joined_user

which is strange because in my `Group` model I have

```
   * Get the users that joined the group.
     */
    public function joinedUsers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'group_joined_user', 'group_id', 'user_id')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }
```

And my `GroupController.php`

```
    public function show($id)
    {
        $group = Group::with('joinedUsers')->where('id', $id)->first();
        return view('groups.show', compact('group'));
    }
```

I have this in my Routes

`Route::resource('groups', 'GroupsController');`

I'm fairly new to Laravel so I might be missing something obvious here?

Comment: You just have to use `$group->joinedUsers`, you never define `$joinedUser` variable

Comment: the only defined variable you have in your view is `$group`. Try `@foreach($group->joinedUsers as $joinedUser)` instead of what you have.

Comment: Cheers guys, sorted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have defined `$group` variable only. `joinedUsers`is the relation and you never defined it as a variable anywhere. you have to do it like

```
@foreach($group->joinedUsers as $user)
    {{$user->name}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: The user name shows up as expected but I'm going in circles trying to link the name to the users' profile page. I am using this link ```<a href="profile/{id}">{{$user->name}}``` which goes to a 'page not found'. The URL is```http://mysite.test/groups/profile/%7Bid%7D```. Any ideas?

Comment: it should be like `<a href="{{ url('profile', $user->id) }}">{{$user->name}}</a>`

Comment: @ zahid hasan emon thank you, it worked! I am new to this so still learning!